# Improved use of link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

My Rails application uses this link format many times in various views:

```
<li><a class="" href="#"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Reports</a></li>
```

So far I have converted it using this format:

```
<li><%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-home"></i> Dashboard'), root_path %></li>
```

Can I take it a step further and somehow refactor the li and i class="icon-home" to clean up the code?

Comment: The gem that helps to DRY out link_to calls: [link_to_action](https://github.com/denispeplin/link_to_action). It is not very suitable for this specific type of link in question, but solves exactly this problem (and some others) for many other types of links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a helper method

```
def menu_link(text, url, icon_class)
  content_tag :li do
    link_to url do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: icon_class) + text
    end.html_safe
  end
end
```

then just call it using

```
<%= menu_link 'Dashboard', root_path, 'icon-home' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Helper method is preferred if you're using this in multiple places (DRY). Check out jvnill's answer for that.

If you want a single line, here you go:

```
<%= content_tag(:li, link_to(content_tag(:i, nil, class: 'icon-home'), root_path)) %>
```

Comment: Thanks looks good. I'll probably use for instances that do not fit the helper method.

Answer (score -1):

This is much better:

```
= link_to new_resource_path, :class=>'btn btn-primary' do
  %i.icon-file-new
  Add Resource
```

Comment: If you're using HAML, which OP is not using.